# Cert Manager - Cluster Issuer Error - tls: handshake failure

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I've setup cert mananger on microk8s following [these](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) instructions, I had it working 6 months ago but have since had to start again from scratch. Now when I setup my Cluster Issuer I'm getting the error below.

Everything else seems fine and in a good state. I'm struggling to know where to start debugging this.

```
Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

Cluster Issuer yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: <myemail>
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: prod-issuer-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

**UPDATE**
Some extra info

All pods for cert manager are running, here are the logs

cert-manager pod [logs](https://pastebin.com/aT5jAVbt)
cert-manager-cainjector logs only shows some warnings about deprecated apis
cert-mananger-webhook [logs](https://pastebin.com/9jbFjdtY)

[Describe ClusterIssuer](https://pastebin.com/V59FdgaK)

I've tried to get a cert for an ingress resource but it errors saying the cluster issuer isn't in a ready state

Comment: Are your pods up and running? Is your network working? Are there any errors in cert-manager pod?

Comment: See updates, no errors really apart from the one in the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uninstalling and reinstalling everything including Microk8s I tried again no luck. Then I tried using the latest helm chart v1.0.2 which had a newer cert-manager version, seemed to work straight away.

Another note, mainly to myself. This issue was also caused by having search domains setup in netplan, once removed everything started working.